# optimize query sql for messenger

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a messages table with 5 millions rows, I want to retrieve the last 10 rows of two users conversation

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                          messages                             |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| message_id | id_sender | id_dest |  subject | message | time  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is the query how I can optimize it?

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT message
    FROM messages 
    WHERE ( id_sender = id1 AND id_dest = id2 ) or
          ( id_dest = id1 AND id_sender = id2 )
    ORDER BY message_id DESC
    LIMIT 10) AS ttbl
ORDER BY message_id ASC
```

Thanks!

I have an index on id_sender id_dest and message_1d

Updated

Comment: What are you trying to optimize? The speed? Do you have indexes? Is this for postgresql or mysql? You've tagged both, but it looks like mysql output.

Comment: Include an explain plan of your query. What version of PostgreSQL are you on?

Comment: Based on the `||` operator for the OR disjunction, this query is for mysql only, so removing the postgresql tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM messages 
      WHERE (id_sender = id1 AND id_dest = id2) or
            (id_dest = id1 AND id_sender = id2)
      ORDER BY message_id DESC
      LIMIT 10
     ) ttbl
ORDER BY message_id ASC;
```

Create an index on `message(id_sender, id_dest, message_id)`.  This will allow the inner query to be satisfied using an index.

I would't worry about the `*` -- it is bad practice to use `*` in operational queries, because the underlying tables might change.  For this, you are choosing 10 records.  The engine will have to look up the 10 records to get all the fields and them sort them (the first sort should be handled by the index).  Sorting 10 records is generally not a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

First note on optimization, it's a lot more involved than *how can I optimize this?*

Secondly, some ideas:

- Don't use `SELECT *` if it's not necessary. Just bring back the fields needed.
- This builds off the first one. Build a covering index. This means that if the fields `a, b, c` are used in the query *anywhere*, then you can build an index on `a, b, c` on the table. This will allow the database to read off the index page rather than having to seek, load, and read from the data page.

Comment: Covered indexes don't exist in all version of PostgreSQL, need 9.2 or greater.  Granted we don't know what system the query is actually targeting based on the tags so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of other options for your `WHERE` clause that you may wish to compare the performance on:

```
WHERE  id1 IN (id_sender, id_dest)
AND    id2 IN (id_sender, id_dest)
```

Can the `id_sender` = `id_dest` ? If not then you can drop the 3rd line off the following `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE  id_sender IN (id1, id2)
AND    id_dest   IN (id1, id2)
AND    id_sender <> id_dest
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the explain plan, I can only guess at the issue. My guess is that your biggest performance hit is with the OR. Try replacing the OR with a union:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM messages 
      WHERE id_sender = id1
      AND id_dest = id2
      ORDER BY message_id DESC
      LIMIT 10

      UNION

      SELECT *
      FROM messages 
      WHERE id_dest = id1
      AND id_sender = id2
      ORDER BY message_id DESC
      LIMIT 10
     ) ttbl
ORDER BY message_id ASC
LIMIT 10;
```